# How to create the Page mock object using mockito in adobe cq5 for writing junits

Tags: junit, mockito, aem

I am using Mockito framework to create mocking objects for writing junits for my Adobe CQ5 project. I have some services that I want to test with JUnit.

I have found a strange issue when I want to create a mock [Page](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html)' object using the below code it gives the following error:

```
Page pageObj = Mockito.mock(Page.class);
```

But this is not the case with other api classess/interfaces

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lcom/day/cq/tagging/Tag;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:349)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:427)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:457)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:93)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:50)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:54)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:44)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:882)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:777)
    at nz.co.telecom.telecomcms.components.PageHelperTest.testIsPageBelowOtherPage(PageHelperTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.day.cq.tagging.Tag
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

If I use any other class to create the mock object, then it works fine for me

```
`PageManager page = mock(PageManager.class)`;//or i use annotations
```

Please advise me why its giving me error only in the case of the Page class in Adobe CQ5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try added the `cq-tagging` dependency to your project.  The exception relates to not being able to find the com.day.cq.tagging.Tag class.  The important part is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lcom/day/cq/tagging/Tag;
```

Checking the cq system console dependency finder:

`http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder?plugin.find=com.day.cq.tagging.Tag&plugin.submit=Find`

reveals that the class can be found in the `com.day.cq.cq-tagging` bundle.  As a maven dependency (on my cq5.5 instance) that is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
  <artifactId>cq-tagging</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You may have a different version if you are using another version of CQ/AEM.  After adding that dependency, I can run the following unit test successfully:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import org.junit.Test;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;

public class PageUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldMockPageObject() {
        Page page = mock(Page.class);
    }
}
```

Overall, the minimum dependencies seem to be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-wcm-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-tagging</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Although if you are failing on tagging then you've probably got everything else you need.

Comment: Thanks Diffa, it seemed to be a problem with the version mismatch. Currently i am on 5.6.1 and also mentioned the version in dependency to be the same, but this jar was not there for this version. Now i have changed it to higher version and it worked for me all the way fine. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I put the link in for the dependency finder `http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder` so you could track down the correct versions.  It's quite a useful tool.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a very useful link tome . Thanks for sharing this. Its a quite handy feature.